# Theming multi-value fields in Views

Tags: views, theming, 8

I added the `field_tags` to my view.

Now I want to add a the tag name as a class name, so I can colour each tag differently.

ex:

```
<div class="tag1">tag1</div>
<div class="tag2">tag2</div>
<div class="tag3">tag3</div>
```

Unfortunately, unchecking [display all values in same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5dKF.jpg) is not an option for me since I need to limit the view to 4 results.

Therefore, somehow I need to be able to loop through them and attach each of them the tag name as a class name.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only work-around solution that I can think of would be to:

Create a separate view for the tags.

Then there I will be able to uncheck [display all values in same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5dKF.jpg).

Re-write field to `<div class="{{ field_tags }}"> {{ field_tags }} </div>`

Then use [View Fields View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to insert the Tags view as a field in my other view and pass the nid as contextual filter.

Probably not the best solution, so if anyone has a better one I'd love to hear it.